# Manage Facebook events in v2.0

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk, social-media

Facebook GraphAPI v.1.0 allowed to manage (create, update, delete) events remotely (via API). This functionality seems not to be available in v2.0 and it says you can NOT create,update,delete (see the screenshot and source below).

V 1.0 will be discontinued from April 2015.  But I can't find any official resources which says how this functionality will be available in the future. How to do it? 
Does anybody know what is the best way to use in our new apps in order to keep the event management stable for long term (beyond 2015?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/events

[image]

Comment: You cannot manage events through the Graph API v2.0 in the future.

Comment: yes, I know but what I need is if there is any workaround like SDK or something to do it? No official solution for the future? We have many apps used by customers and I am looking for a long term solution.

Comment: There is none, and the docs clearly describe that. The `create_events` permission has been removed with v2.0, so how should this even work? FB apparantly doesn't want this functionality to be available to apps...